Differences in the rate of circumcision by US state
Why are circumcision rates lower in the west than in the rest of the US?

This graph is from this article by the NPR health correspondent.
https://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2013/08/22/214406903/popularity-of-circumcision-falls-in-u-s-especially-out-west
But the NPR health correspondent took the graph from the CDC.
According to this paper, it is affected by whether the state's Medicaid policies pay for circumcision or not. This wouldn't explain all of the difference.
This is fundamentally a question about sociology, but sociology of illness is an aspect of public health.
There is no StackExchange network on sociology, so I am putting this question under the public health tag here. The reasons why this is a "public health" question are that there are public health tradeoffs apparently on both sides of the equation.

This study finds that more than 100 neonatal circumcision-related deaths (9.01/100,000) occur annually in the United States, about 1.3% of male neonatal deaths from all causes. Because infant circumcision is elective, all of these deaths are avoidable.


A risk-benefit analysis of conditions that neonatal circumcision protects against revealed that benefits exceed risks by at least 100 to 1 and that over their lifetime, half of uncircumcised males will require treatment for a medical condition associated with retention of the foreskin.

I asked this question before, and it was removed for being too political/cultural. This  makes no sense, given that religion and personal political orientation do affect other aspects of "public health".

Religion affects adherence to social distancing


Political orientation affects adherence to social distancing


Religiosity and abortion


Religiosity affects condom usage

A similar thing (seatbelt usage), which seems to be "cultural", can also be analysed through the lens of "public health", and the demographic factors that affect it are considered:

Previous studies have identified some important factors that affect belt use rates, including gender, age, race, vehicle type, seat-belt enforcement laws, and amount of fine for belt-use law violation.

Has there been any thorough examination of which factors affect circumcision, besides whether or not a state's Medicaid program pays for it? How much does religion affect the rate of circumcision? How much does political orientation affect the rate of circumcision?

You've not had any questions removed here. For future reference, when a question gets closed, the way you handle that is to [edit] it to correct the issues, not by writing an entirely new question. Once you edit, it becomes eligible for reopening, which can be done with 3 votes from high-rep members or one vote from a moderator. Anyway, this question is much better so I'm just going to delete your previous question since it's pretty much a duplicate.

I think the question would be broadly unanswerable without significant research into why people in the Western US are less likely to circumcise their children.  Would need to poll, and probably over several years/generations to have any kind of validity.  I did a brief look, and couldn't find anyone who is doing that research, and I also couldn't find anyone that I think would fund that research.  It's not enough of a medical concern either way.

@AtlLED - When the American Academy of Pediatrics recommends circumcision, it's a medical issue. Non-circumcised males have a higher incidence of urogenital problems than circumcised males. It's been studied, and barriers to circumcision are being studied.

@anongoodnurse Thank you for posting that, on re-reading my own comment I realize it comes across with a much a different point than I intended.  I know it's a medical issue, and it is definitely worth study.  When I looked through the US NIH grants, I couldn't find any that focused on barriers to circumcision within the US regionally, and most were focused on Africa, though Dr. Holl's group is doing interesting work in Chicago. Coming from the ID side, I want to be clear that the evidence supports circumcision from an infection control perspective.
